# MacOS Ventura Update issues with external monitor

Tags: macos, display, upgrade, ventura

I am having issues with the new MacOS ventura upgrade. My external monitor keeps disconnecting and I couldn't use the laptop on clamshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was connecting my Mac to power via the Magsafe charger. This seems to resolve the external monitor connection issues for me.